# Ignore order of mysql record in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code that currently *almost* does what I need. It needs to select all records from a table and then format them ready for encoding to JSON. However, ONE record will have a "type" field set as "default". This record is placed first in the JSON file and formatted slightly different.

Currently this works prefectly if the record set to default is the last entry in the database table. But, if it isn't, then the formatting breaks when encoding to JSON.

Can anyone help suggest a fix that would force it to ignore where the default entry is, but retain the formatting?

```
// Get the data from the DB.

$query = 'SELECT  type, headline, startDate, text, media, caption, credits FROM #__timeline_entries'.$table.'';
$db->setQuery($query);
// Load it and put it into an array

$list = $db->loadObjectList();

$len = count($list);

$data = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
$temp = (array) $list[$i];

$temp["asset"] = array(
    "media" => $temp["media"],
    "credit" => $temp["credits"],
    "caption" => $temp["caption"]
);
unset($temp["media"]);
unset($temp["credits"]);
unset($temp["caption"]);

if ($temp["type"] == "default") {
    $data = $list[$i];
    unset($list[$i]);

    $list[$i] = $temp;
  }
}

// Prep it for JSON
$data->date = &$list;

// Loop it once more!
$dataTwo->timeline = &$data;

// Encode the data to JSON.
$jsondata = json_encode($dataTwo);
```

This is part of a Joomla component, but it doesn't really use any of the Joomla framework beyond the database connection. I thought I'd mention it just in case it made any difference, though I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER by (type = "default")
```

This will be 0 for all the records except the default, which is 1, so it will be put last.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WHERE clause to your MySQL statement:

```
$query = 'SELECT  type, headline, startDate, text, media, caption, credits FROM #__timeline_entries'.$table.' WHERE type <> default';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion, but this seems to break it again. Nothing is output to JSON at all. I do need the default record to be included, I just need the script to not care where in the database it exists, as that seems to be the problem. If I create the default record last, it works. Change any other record to default and it breaks. :(